# How can I prevent initialization of an exported type in Go?

Tags: go, null, segmentation-fault, initialization

Edit: I'm not asking how to initialize variables correctly.  I'm asking how to *prevent* them from being initialized *incorrectly*, so that functions that take that type don't have to explicitly validate their arguments.

In Go, I have a type that contains maps, e.g.:

```
package foo

type Bar struct {
  baz map[string]int
  total int
}

func NewBar() *Bar {
  return &Bar{baz: map[string]int{}}
}

func (b *Bar) IncrementBaz(key string) {
    f.baz[key] = f.baz[key] + 1
    f.total++
}

// ...
```

If another package initializes the type and then tries to write to it, it will try to write to a nil map, causing a segfault:

```
package main

import "foo"

func main() {
  var b foo.Bar
  b.IncrementBaz("some_key") // write to nil map -> segfault
  // ...
}
```

To prevent this, I want to make it so that other packages can't initialize an empty `foo.Bar`.

I can't simply make it unexported, because I want functions in other packages to be able to declare it as an argument or return type.  If I wrap it in an interface, I get a similar problem:

```
package "foo"

type Bar interface {
  IncrementBaz(string)
  // ...
}

type bar struct {
  baz map[string]int
  total int
}

func NewBar() Bar {
  return &bar{baz: map[string]int{}}
}

func (b *bar) IncrementBaz(key string) {
    f.baz[key] = f.baz[key] + 1
    f.total++
}

// ...
```

Similar problem:

```
package main

import "foo"

func main() {
  var b foo.Bar
  b.IncrementBaz("some_key") // method call on nil interface -> segfault
  // ...
}
```

Is there any way to have an exported type that only the package that declares it can initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

Now `foo.Bar` is just an interface type. The default value is a nil pointer. You are very close, just initialize it as `b := foo.NewBar()`

Comment: An interface type can be `nil`, which means any function that takes that type has to either nil-check it or risk panicking when it tries to call a method on it, which is what I'm trying to avoid.